# Javascript attributes slowing down dynamic table

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a table that is dynamically created in some c# code-behind when a dropdown is changed.  There 9 columns in this table.  The first 8 should be in one group.  The last attribute in another.  When the last attribute is selected I want the first 8 to go unchecked. When any of the first 8 are checked I wanted the last attribute to go unchecked.  I added some javascript and it works but it causes the tables to load extremely slow. If there is a simpler way please let me know.  Thanks!

adding javascript function calls through c#

```
attr1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr2.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr3.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr4.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr5.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr6.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr7.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr8.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckOK(" + rowCount + ");");

attr9.Attributes.Add("onClick", "uncheckAttr(" + rowCount + ");");
```

functions to uncheck

```
function uncheckAttr(row) {
    var chk1 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr1-" + row);
    chk1.checked = false;
    var chk2 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr2-" + row);
    chk2.checked = false;
    var chk3 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr3-" + row);
    chk3.checked = false;
    var chk4 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr4-" + row);
    chk4.checked = false;
    var chk5 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr5-" + row);
    chk5.checked = false;
    var chk6 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr6-" + row);
    chk6.checked = false;
    var chk7 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr7-" + row);
    chk7.checked = false;
    var chk8 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr8-" + row);
    chk8.checked = false;
}
function uncheckOK(row) {
    var chk9 = document.getElementById("MainContent_attr9-" + row);
    chk9.checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Can't last row be removed and placed in table footer? It would be easier to make this generic.

Comment: Adding JavaScript event handlers at the DOM Level 0 is generally discouraged. You could create an event listener that listens at the table level that handles all the checkboxes within it. It would be much easier to achieve if you were using a framework rather that attempting to write it in pure JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks OriginalSyn I went higher up in DOM and added a single onclick to the table and then you can use event.srcElement to see if it was a checkbox and which one. Love you long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function uncheck() {
    var clickSource = event.srcElement;
    if (clickSource != null) {
        var fullid = clickSource.name;
        if (fullid != null) {
            if (fullid.indexOf('attr') != -1) {
                var checkboxid = fullid.substring(fullid.indexOf('attr'));
                var row = checkboxid.substring(checkboxid.indexOf('-') + 1);
                var attr = checkboxid.substring(checkboxid.indexOf('-') - 1, checkboxid.indexOf('-'));
                if (attr == '9') {
                    uncheckAttr(row);
                }
                else {
                    uncheckOK(row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this via standard HTML? Make a set of radio buttons - give columns 1-8 the same `name` attribute, and give the 9th one a different `name`. You should only be able to select one or the other.

Alternatively, strip out that ugly code and use some jQuery. Something like:

```
$('table.your-table input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('table.your-table input[type=radio]').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

EDIT: Actually the HTML option won't work, but I encourage you to do this via jQuery, it's what it's built for.